# AWS Lambda DynamoDb 500 Internal Error on getitem

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam

I am able to getitems from Postman using a localhost but not the Lambda endpoint. I get a 500 internal status error.

I used NET 3.0 to upload a Lambda function to AWS that uses DynamoDB. I added a policy to the automatically role for this Lambda Function to access my DynamoDB.  This is the policy

```
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:getitem",
                "dynamodb:deleteitem",
                "dynamodb:createtable",
                "dynamodb:describetable",
                "dynamodb:putitem",
                "dynamodb:updateitem"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:97zzzzz:table/BlogDynamoDbTable"
        }
    ]
}
```

What else may I be missing?

This is the log output:

```

16:20:21
[Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware: Executed endpoint 'AWSServerlessDynamoDb.Controllers.DynamoDbController.GetItems (AWSServerlessDynamoDb)'
[Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware: Executed endpoint 'AWSServerlessDynamoDb.Controllers.DynamoDbController.GetItems (AWSServerlessDynamoDb)' 

16:20:21
[41m[30mfail[39m[22m[49m: Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.AbstractAspNetCoreFunction[0]
[41m[30mfail[39m[22m[49m: Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.AbstractAspNetCoreFunction[0]

16:20:21
Unknown error responding to request: AmazonServiceException:
Unknown error responding to request: AmazonServiceException:

16:20:21
Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceException: Unable to get IAM security credentials from EC2 Instance Metadata Service.
```

Comment: Can you check the lambda logs for exact error?

Comment: Thanks. I was not aware I could do this. I will look at this.

Comment: @OleksiiDonoha  I added the before and after the error in the log.

Comment: Do you launch the script on EC2 instance? If yes, you need to attach role with proper permissions to that instance

Comment: @OleksiiDonoha I did not launch an EC2 instance. This worked fine in Postman to access the dynamo database. I opened a github issue. Hopefully I get a response.